# When I want to generate apk file: UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task property during up-to-date check

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I face this problem when I want to generatedsigned apk file

This from Build Output Bar

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:preReleaseBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:333)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at...
```

Answer (score 0):

Go Settings/Gradle/Android Studio. Then check "Enable embedded Maven repository". And you're good to go.

[image]